# How to resolve CWE-259 (hard-coded password) in PHP/MySQL on shared hosting?

Tags: php, mysql, security, passwords

I have a PHP/MySQL website hosted on GoDaddy. I am trying to remove all security flaws from the site.

To connect to my database, I have a file that is "Connect.php" that I include in all the necessary PHP files. It consists of the following code:

```
<?php
//Connect To Database
$hostname='xyz.hostedresource.com';
$username='username';
$password='password';
$dbname='dbname';
?>
```

I understand a common fix to address the use of hard-coded passwords is to store the password in a config file outside of the webroot folder. However, with GoDaddy shared hosting, I do not have access to anything outside of the webroot folder. Does anyone have any suggestions to resolve this CWE in this situation?

Comment: one of the many reasons to never use godaddy hosting

Comment: Does this host not have a `public_html` folder as a subfolder of the main account? 99% of the others do, and that is where files meant to be outside of the docroot would go.

Comment: @Dagon, that _is_ a weird configuration. But then, [I'd not use them anyway](http://mashable.com/2011/12/23/godaddy-ceo-mashable-sopa-support-reversal/).

Comment: @Dagon - in hindsight, I wish I had gone with another hoster, but this application is not revenue generating so I went with a cheap option. Think there is any solution or am I SOL?

Comment: you can create a directory protected with .htacess file, but  will still be-inside the root so could still be exposed by a server fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP the issue is (or could be) that the interpreter stops interpreting and the files are served as plain text.

In your case, perhaps this is as far as you can go:

- Put 'hidden' files in a folder, and prevent access to that folder using .htaccess and other Apache directives. This is actually not that far off having it in a separate folder (since Apache and its configuration are managing the security for you either way).

and:

- Remove the ability for the MySQL server to be accessed outside of the local machine/IP address you're using. I'm not sure if you can do this with your hosting provider (or to what extent you can single yourself out)